# Get height of uiview added by autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am added a view in viewDidAppear method using autolayout. In the end of viewDidAppear trying to find the height of view that I added , I am getting zero?

That view I am adding has a label , height of that label is dynamic

```
let viewToShowIn = self.view!
let bannerView = UIView()
bannerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let label = UILabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

viewToShowIn.addSubview(bannerView)
bannerView.addSubview(label)

let margins = viewToShowIn.layoutMarginsGuide

bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToShowIn.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToShowIn.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
let bannerTopConstraint =    bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 0)
bannerTopConstraint.isActive = true

label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
label.text = "kjafj kfj fk fjk dakjd k fdjakljf dkfjklsdjf dfsjlkj lkfsdjlkjl sjflksdjfljslf sdfljdslkjflsdjf sldfjlksj"
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.textAlignment = .center

label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

Comment: You can use `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize)` and pass either `UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` (the least possible) or `UILayoutFittingExpandedSize` (the largest possible). This will return the optimal size of the view based on its current constraints. If you get a zero width/height, it means that you have not provided enough constraints for that dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your label and view as global variable like

```
var viewToShowIn = UIView()
let bannerView = UIView()
let label = UILabel()
```

Then set constraints in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLoad`

```
    viewToShowIn = self.view!
    bannerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    viewToShowIn.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.addSubview(label)

    let margins = viewToShowIn.layoutMarginsGuide

    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    bannerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToShowIn.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    bannerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToShowIn.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    let bannerTopConstraint =    bannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 0)
    bannerTopConstraint.isActive = true

    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label.text = "kjafj kfj fk fjk dakjd k fdjakljf dkfjklsdjf dfsjlkj lkfsdjlkjl sjflksdjfljslf sdfljdslkjflsdjf sldfjlksj"
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .center

    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

You will get height of your view or label in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // GET YOUR HEIGHT HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding all constraints to view just call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

It will force auto layout engine to calculate view size.